# Deploying a WAR file to Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, web, deployment, war

I am trying to deploy a web application (WAR file) to Tomcat 7 using the command line, but i'm doing something wrong.
I keep getting the 404 error, but I can access the html files using the localhost:8080/App_hame/file_name.html syntax.

I deploy files to server this way: I set the CATALINA_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables, start the server this way:

```
SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\my_path\apache-tomcat-7.0.69
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
startup.bat
```

Then I copy the WAR file to webapps folder of the server and then restart the server.
I can see the file unpacking to an App_name directory in webapps folder, but i can't access the application from the browser using the mentioned url.

I am probably missing a step or so, so please, can somebody explain it to me what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks to anyone who replies!

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have an entry in your web.xml mapping your servlet to the url-pattern

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EntryServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Nope, it's not that.